# Append new characters to a Palindrome. Efficient or Dynamic way to check if the new string still a Palindrome?

Tags: algorithm, palindrome

Say I have a palindrome `s` and I am going to keep appending characters at the end of `s` for fun. But I want to stop once s is no longer a palindrome.

Now I am lazy so I don't want to rescan `s` to determine if it is a palindrome every time when a new character is appended to `s`. I am wondering if there a faster way to formularize/check if the new `s` is a palindrome by utilizing that the fact that `s` is already a palindrome. I feel there is a way to utilize that information but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

---

I am stuck on my thinking process. so far I am trying to break things down into cases.

the palindrome `s` can be in two form: (`|__M__|` is a substring portion of `s` and `|__-M__|` is the reverse of `|__M__|`)

when the length is odd:

`|__-M__|X|__M__|`

when the length is even:

`|__-M__||__M__|`

now when I append the new character `c` is there an efficient way to check

`|__-M__|X|__M__|c`   <---- a palindrome?

`|__-M__||__M__|c` <---- a palindrome?

Comment: Can you give some examples of palindromes (of even length, odd length, or both) that would satisfy this criteria? Off the top of my head I can only think of palindromes of one character, and appending that same character, e.g. aaa --> aaaa

Comment: @Keeler now you asked I think I over was thinking the problem.....I think the only time the palindrome remain to be a palindrome is if all characters is the same and we add the same characters. (plus the empty string case).....right? man now I feel foolish......why am I losing sleep for a simple question like this....sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formalizing the same-character conjecture from the comments:

If not all characters in the string `S` having `N` characters are the same, there must be:

- a character `C1` at index `P1`, followed by a different `C2` at `P1+1`
- a `C1` at the mirror index `N-1-P1`, preceded by `C2` at `N-2-P1`

After adding any single character to S, now there must be:

- a character `C1` at index `P1`, followed by `C2` at `P1+1`
- a `C1` at mirror index, now being `N-P1`, preceded by `C2` at `N-1-P1`

So, the character at `N-1-P1` must be both `C1` (before the extension) and `C2` (after the extension) which is impossible as we said they are different.

So, only if the original string is a repetition of one single charater, is it possible to extend it character-per-character and keep it being a palindrome.